# NSInternalConsistencyException unexpected start date NSRunLoop

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code in a couple places (applicationWillEnterForeground, didReceiveRemoteNotification) of my app delegate.

```
    //create the semaphore
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    /* ... redacted code that does some other stuff ... */

    // Wait up to 30 seconds for reauth
    int ntimeout = 3;

    //holds the thread until the dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore); is send
    while ((dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW)) && ( ntimeout > 0 ))
    {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10]];

        ntimeout --;
    }
```

The issue is that we're occasionally getting crashes on the [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode line with the following:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x181f5edb0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1815c3f80 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x181f5ec80 +[NSException raise:format:]
3  Foundation                     0x1828e41c0 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  UIKit                          0x187380984 _prepareForCAFlush
5  UIKit                          0x187380820 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_2
6  CoreFoundation                 0x181f14f84 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
7  CoreFoundation                 0x181f148bc __CFRunLoopDoBlocks
8  CoreFoundation                 0x181f12820 __CFRunLoopRun
9  CoreFoundation                 0x181e3cc50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
10 Foundation                     0x18284ccfc -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What are you trying to do here (why are you manually scheduling the run loop)? And who's calling `dispatch_semaphore_signal`?

Comment: Your code comment says `//holds the thread until the dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)`, but `dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW)` has an instantaneous timeout. It's not waiting for anything, ever.